# Allow admins to translate interface strings on a headless/decoupled site

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

I have a list of common UI strings that will appear in multiple places across my headless Drupal site's webpages. Things like "more", "next", "continue", etc.

I'd like to allow admins translate these in one place. The interface translation UI (from the core Interface Translation module) is promising but because I'm not using Drupal templates, I don't have a way to get the strings into, or out of, Drupal.

Do you have any idea on how to go about setting this up?

Comment: Are you using `t()` calls inside a module, or doing this all through the UI?

Comment: I'm looking for site admins to be able to manage this through the UI, like they can with fields translations.

Comment: What's wrong with the **User interface translation** under `admin/config/regional/translate`? There you have one place for all strings which are translatable.

Comment: @RWAM thank's for the suggestion. That's close to what I'm looking for, but that list only has pre-defined strings, for text used in the CMS Interface. I'm looking for something like this, except I'd be able to add a bunch of arbitrary strings, so I can translate custom text that could be displayed in a consumer-facing interface.

Comment: @RWAM, oh, I'm seeing that you add arbitrary strings to this list via the `t()` function (in its various forms... twig, etc). So this **User interface translation** _could be_ the right tool, but I'd have to find my own way to add terms (since I'm not using drupal templates), and a way to expose them via JSON.

Comment: Shot in the dark, but wouldn't incoming requests need to specify the language code?

Comment: @bryanbraun How did you solve the issue finally?

Comment: I didn't solve it yet... other things were prioritized. I was expecting we'd have to do this with a custom module that lets you to add/import UI Translation strings via a form, and then exposes them via a json endpoint.

Comment: The import part itself is possible in Drupal8. You can import Gettext Portable Object  files. However, I don't see a way to export them with the GraphQL module.